# C# wpf DbContext Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a problem with my code. In `MainWindowVM.Cs` class on the `TegevusedProjektis = _projektService.GetAllTegevusedProjektides;` it says the following error:
[image]

I don't know how to fix it, could somebody help me.

My `MainWindowVM.cs` code:

```
public class MainWindowVM : BaseVM
{
    private List<Projekt> _projekts;
    private List<Tegevus> _tegevused;
    private List<TegevusProjektis> _tegevusedProjektis;

    private IProjektInterface _projektService;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _projekts = new List<Projekt>();
        _tegevused = new List<Tegevus>();
        _tegevusedProjektis = new List<TegevusProjektis>();
        _projektService = new ProjektService(new ProjektDbContext());
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        Projektid = _projektService.GetAllProjekts();
        Tegevused = _projektService.GetAllTegevused();
        TegevusedProjektis = _projektService.GetAllTegevusedProjektides;
    }

    public List<Projekt> Projektid
    {
        get { return _projekts; }
        set
        {
            _projekts = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Projekts");
        }
    }

    public List<Tegevus> Tegevused
    {
        get { return _tegevused; }
        set
        {
            _tegevused = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Tegevused");
        }
    }

    public List<TegevusProjektis> TegevusedProjektis
    {
        get { return _tegevusedProjektis; }
        set
        {
            _tegevusedProjektis = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("TegevusedProjektis");
        }
    }


}
```

This is my `ProjectService.cs` code:

```
 public class ProjektService : BaseService
{
    public ProjektService(ProjektDbContext ctx) : base(ctx)
    {
    }

    public List<Projekt> GetAllProjekts()
    {
        return base.DataContext.Projektid.ToList();
    }

    public List<Tegevus> GetAllTegevused()
    {
        return base.DataContext.Tegevused.ToList();
    }

    public List<TegevusProjektis> GetAllTegevusedProjektis()
    {
        return base.DataContext.TegevusedProjektides.ToList();
    }

    public Projekt GetProjektById(int id)
    {
        return DataContext.Projektid.Where(x => x.ProjektId == id).Single();
    }

    public Tegevus GetTegevusById(int id)
    {
        return DataContext.Tegevused.Where(x => x.TegevusId == id).Single();
    }

    public TegevusProjektis GetTegevusProjektisById(int id)
    {
        return DataContext.TegevusedProjektides.Where(x => x.TegevusProjektisId == id).Single();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the class definition for `ProjektService`. I'm pretty sure it doesn't implement the `IProjektInterface` that you're expecting it to.

Comment: Did you get error when converting explicitly as compiler mentioned?

Comment: Added `ProjektService` code

Comment: ProjektService.cs does not seemt to contain function GetAllTegevusedProjektides? Is it in BaseService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have captured the relevant bit of your code below.

```
public class MainWindowVM : BaseVM
{
    private IProjektInterface _projektService;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _projektService = new ProjektService(new ProjektDbContext());
    }
}

public class ProjektService : BaseService
{ }
```

As is, `ProjektService` doesn't implement `IProjektInterface`. You can address this in one of two ways.

You can change the type of your private field.

```
private ProjektService _projektService;
```

Or you can implement your interface in `ProjektService`.

```
public class ProjektService : BaseService, IProjektInterface
{ }
```